# Java, unit test mocking mxbean

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mxbean

I want to sort all the Java threads on CPU time. I use the ThreadMXBean to get the CPU time of the threads by thread ID. The comparator is used for sortinging the Thread ID's.

```
public class ThreadStats{
    private static ThreadMXBean mxbean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();

    class ThreadCPUCompare implements Comparator<Long>{

        @Override
        public int compare(Long threadId1, Long threadId2) {
            return Long.compare(mxbean.getThreadCpuTime(threadId2), mxbean.getThreadCpuTime(threadId1));
        }
    }
}
```

And I've made the following unit test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ThreadStatsTest {

@InjectMocks ThreadCPUCompare comperator = new ThreadStats().new ThreadCPUCompare();
@Mock ThreadMXBean mxbean;

@Test
public void threadCPUSortTest() {
    Mockito.when(mxbean.getThreadCpuTime(1L)).thenReturn(3L);
    Mockito.when(mxbean.getThreadCpuTime(2L)).thenReturn(2L);
    Mockito.when(mxbean.getThreadCpuTime(3L)).thenReturn(4L);
    Mockito.when(mxbean.getThreadCpuTime(4L)).thenReturn(1L);

    List<Long>expectedList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    expectedList.add(3L);
    expectedList.add(1L);
    expectedList.add(2L);
    expectedList.add(4L);

    List<Long>actualList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    actualList.add(4L);
    actualList.add(2L);
    actualList.add(3L);
    actualList.add(1L);


    //Sorting of the actual list
    Collections.sort(actualList, comperator);

    assertEquals(expectedList, actualList);
    }
}
```

But I cant get the test to work. I think because the mocking doesn't work. Could someone show me how to fix the unit test please?

Comment: Not sure but wouldn't you require to invoke `verify(mxbean)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test is failing because the mock is not being injected. Mockito will not inject into static fields, nor will it inject into an outer class (such as the `ThreadStats` class in your case).

You need to write the code as something like this:

```
class ThreadCPUCompare implements Comparator<Long>
{
    private ThreadMXBean mxbean;

    @Override
    public int compare(Long threadId1, Long threadId2) {
        return Long.compare(mxbean.getThreadCpuTime(threadId2), mxbean.getThreadCpuTime(threadId1));
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ThreadStatsTest
{
    @Mock ThreadMXBean mxbean;
    @InjectMocks Comparator comperator = new ThreadCPUCompare();

    @Test
    public void threadCPUSortTest() {
        // do your tests exactly as before
    }
}
```

You will then have the challenge of wiring it into the production code, but that is a different exercise, where I would recommend some sort of dependency injection (guice, spring, manual etc depending on context and preferences).

Comment: Or, just leave the code as is, and write the test with no mocking. In this case, the test can simply use two or three threads with a known relation between their CPU times (say, `Thread.currentThread()` and a `new Thread()`). Mocking is over-rated and best avoided, and situations like this only confirm it.

Comment: @Rogério, do you really think creating real threads and trying to control their cpu times would be a more elegant solution than mocking the dependency to ThreadMXBean? Please share that solution in that case.

Comment: Ok, I added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to write the test is as follows, no mocking involved:

```
public class ThreadStatsTest {
    Comparator<Long> comparator = new ThreadStats().new ThreadCPUCompare();

    @Test
    public void orderThreadIdsFromLongestToShortestCPUTime() {
        long longLivedThread = Thread.currentThread().getId(); // > 0 cpu time
        long shortLivedThread = new Thread().getId(); // 0 cpu time

        int longTimeFirst = comparator.compare(longLivedThread, shortLivedThread);
        int sameTimes = comparator.compare(longLivedThread, longLivedThread);
        int longTimeSecond = comparator.compare(shortLivedThread, longLivedThread);

        assertEquals(-1, longTimeFirst);
        assertEquals( 0, sameTimes);
        assertEquals( 1, longTimeSecond);
    }
}
```